# How do I approach multiplatform app with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, multiplatform, react-native-web, expo-web

I'm just learning development and recently, I finished a MERN stack course.

Now I'm wanting to build my second Commercial App for the company where I am working.
At first, I was only considering responsive web platform but now, I can't deny the necessity of functionality on ios and Android.

Thus, I did my own research on which framework or method I will have to use to minimize my production time rather than using react web and react native separately.
It seems like Expo Web and React Native Web will be the closest solution I can think of.

I'm not sure if I'm trying to take things too easy, but if someone can enlighten me with suggestions on how to approach this dillema, that will be greatly appreciated.

In Short.

**What is better? Expo Web or Native Web and best way to learn..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Expo, you're building the same app for iOS, Android, and Web at the same time.

Building an app with Expo CLI will provide a 100% code base across the 3 platforms. Because the Expo SDK covers most, if not, all the tools you need to build a simple application without touching native code.

Expo also offers you the possibility to eject from it, if by any chance you need to change native code.

I would suggest that you start with Expo CLI, because of how rich its SDK is and how easy it is to get started with it. And if later in time you wanna modify native code, you can eject from it.

Comment: Hi butbansky, thanks a lot for your opinion, I will start looking at it right away. I fact, your answer is the only input I received from this question I posted in multiple places. Maybe my question itself is too vague, but really appreciate your valuable insight.